# Detect if column have date values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas-groupby, sklearn-pandas

I have a dataframe where I have a column "Date series". In that column some rows have time(23:59:52) only and some rows have date(9/15/2019) only. I want to make a new column based on this column. If "Date series" column have date then make a new column and print that date in all rows where "Date series" column have date. If "Date Series" have time and the new column should have time printed

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to differentiate the format.
For example, formatting for time has colons(:) and dates have forward slash(/)

In the following code bits, we are going to set up a regex compiler which detects numbers with colons. If the regex matching gives us an output, it will be a time, if not it's a date

```
import re

re_time = re.compile(r'\d+:\d+:\d+')    #our regex compiler
for row in column:                      #for each row in column
    if re_time.match(row):
         # the string contained in row is 'time' format
    else:
         # the string contained in row is 'date' format
```

In case you want to create regex compiler for date formatting, you can use

```
re_date = re.compile(r'\d+/\d+/\d+')
```